# Getting HTML File to connect to files which in turn connect to a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need the HTML File below to connect to different PHP Files as these connect to different tables in a database. I have used JAVA Script to submit an action when the button is pressed but no matter what, the file will only connect to the Prepared.php file and never connect to the Prepared2.php file. Ihave tried labeling differently and many other concepts but cannot seem to get the file to work.

Please find code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> BBC Database search </title>

</head>
<body>
<center> 
<h1> BBC Database search </h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitAction(act) {
     document.sample.action = act;
     document.sample.submit();

    }
    </script>

<form action="Prepared.php" method="post">  
Search Brands: <input type="text" name="term" 
onClick="submitAction('Prepared.php')"/><br />  
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  /> 

<form action="Prepared2.php" method="post">  
Search Available Clips: <input type="text" name="clips" 
onClick="submitAction('Prepared2.php')" /><br />  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"  /> 
  </center>
  </form>
```

Comment: there's no php or mysql here which already makes the question unclear.

Comment: you also didn't close off the first form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js code is totally unnecessary, and wrong, remove it and the onsubmit.

Then close the first `<form>` tag with a `</form>` Currently you have the second form within the first and thats not legal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> BBC Database search </title>

</head>
<body>
<center> 
<h1> BBC Database search </h1>
<form action="Prepared.php" method="post">  
    Search Brands: <input type="text" name="term" />
    <br />  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

<form action="Prepared2.php" method="post">  
    Search Available Clips: <input type="text" name="clips" />
    <br />  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```